# How to assign Azure AD PIM to a custom RBAC role using BICEP

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-bicep, elevated-privileges, azure-rbac

How to assign Azure AD PIM to a custom RBAC role using BICEP

I am trying to use the below BICEP template to assign PIM to the custom RBAC role at the subscription level of scope.
targetScope = 'subscription'
param startTime string = utcNow()

```
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests@2022-04-01-preview' = {
  name: 'string'
  scope: subscription()
  properties: {
    principalId: 'xxxx'
    requestType: 'AdminAssign'
    roleDefinitionId:'xxxx'  
    scheduleInfo: {
      expiration: {
        duration: 'P365D'
        //endDateTime: 'string'
        type: 'AfterDuration'
      }
      startDateTime: startTime
    }
   /* targetRoleEligibilityScheduleId: 'xxxxx'
    targetRoleEligibilityScheduleInstanceId: 'string'
    ticketInfo: {
      ticketNumber: 'string'
      ticketSystem: 'string' 
    }*/
  }
}
```

For the PrincipalID, I have provided the object id of the Azure AD Group.
For the roleDefinitionID, I have provided the role def id of the custom role.

However, I am facing the error, while deploying through Azure CLI:

```json
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
    "target": "/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Mscript",
    "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidRoleAssignmentRequest",
        "message": "The role assignment request id is invalid."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Kindly provide a resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> "The role assignment request id is invalid.":

I also received the same error when I tried in my environment as shown.

[image]

I found why it is failing the request after performed a workaround on your issue. As per the naming constraints in bicep, you must provide the `Request ID`in a proper and unique format, which is something like `name: guid(resourceGroup().id, principalId, 'abcxx')`.

```bash
targetScope = 'subscription'
param startTime string = utcNow()
param roleDefinitionId string = 'xxxxx'
param principalId string = 'xxx'
param subscriptionId string = 'xxxx'

resource pimAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests@2022-04-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(subscription().id, principalId, roleDefinitionId, 'abcxxx')
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    requestType: 'AdminAssign'
    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
    scheduleInfo: {
      expiration: {
        duration: 'P365D'
        type: 'AfterDuration'
      }
      startDateTime: startTime
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Refer this [document](https://samcogan.com/assign-azure-privileged-identity-management-roles-using-bicep/) for more relevant information.

Comment: Hi @Jahnavi, Thank you for your response. Could you please let me know, how and where I can get the Request ID. Also, I am trying to deploy this at a subscription level. Kindly guide me.

Comment: `RequestID` is nothing but the `name` that you are passing to the resource. If you want to deploy it at a subscription level, use `az deployment sub create` command with the  

`--location` parameter. @Sunshine

Comment: Hi @Jahnavi, I would like to confirm the value that you have provided in role.bicep and role1.bicep. Because I am receiving an error that the subscriptionId parameter is not declared anywhere. And also, for the RequestID could you please confirm the value to be provided, as I am not sure what the resource here is.

Comment: Resource is nothing but this `resource pimAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests@2022-04-01-preview'`. And for the error `subscription ID` is not declared anywhere, you need to declare it as a `param subscriptionID string = 'xxx'` as I explained in the above answer. @Sunshine